# Use a mutex as a semaphore?

Tags: c++, concurrency, c++11, mutex, semaphore

I need two threads to progress in a *"tick tock"* pattern.  When implmented with a semaphore this looks fine:

```
Semaphore tick_sem(1);
Semaphore tock_sem(0);

void ticker( void )
{
   while( true )
   {
      P( tick_sem );
      do_tick();
      V( tock_sem );
   }
}

void tocker( void )
{
   while( true )
   {
      P( tock_sem );
      do_tock();
      V( tick_sem );
   }
}
```

However, if I do the same thing with a mutex ( which is technically a binary semaphore ), it has an odd code smell.

```
std::mutex tick_mutex;
std::mutex tock_mutex;
tock_mutex.lock();

void ticker( void )
{
   while( true )
   {
      tick_mutex.lock();
      do_tick();
      tock_mutex.unlock();
   }
}

void tocker( void )
{
   while( true )
   {
      tock_mutex.lock()
      do_tock();
      tick_mutex.unlock();
   }
}
```

I think the smell is that a mutex isn't meant to convey information to another thread.  (The c++11 standard committee added a spurious fail to try_lock to defeat unexpected information transfer; §30.4.1/14.)  It seems like mutexes are meant to synchronize access to a variable, which can then convey information to another thread.

Lastly, when implemented with a `std::condition_variable`, it looks correct but it's more complicated ( a tick_vs_tock variable, a mutex, and a condition variable).  I've omitted the implementation for brevity, but it's really straight forward.

Is the mutex solution fine?  Or is there something subtly wrong with it?

Is there a good pattern for solving my tick/tock problem that I haven't thought of?

Comment: BTW: this issue only arose because C++0x doesn't have a `std::semaphore` and the double `std::mutex` solution is less complicated than the `std::condition_variable` solution.

Comment: (Why) is it even valid to `unlock()` a mutex in a thread that doesn't currently hold it?

Comment: @Steve that is really good question (hint, hint, nudge, nudge).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A Mutex is not simply just a binary semaphore, it also has the limitation that only the locking thread is allowed to unlock it.

You are breaking that rule.

*Edit:*

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685066):

> The ReleaseMutex function fails if the calling thread does not own the
>   mutex object.

From some site that google turned up for [pthread_mutex_unlock](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/man/pthread_mutex_unlock.txt):

> The pthread_mutex_unlock() function may fail if:
>
> EPERM  The current thread does not own the mutex.

And you will find the same on other mutex implementations. It makes sense because a mutex is supposed to guard a thread's access to a resource, so another thread should not be able to unlock it.

Comment: As per Steve's comment.  Is that really a rule?  It's definitely a good idea.

Comment: @deft - I think it depends on the implementation of the mutex, which is system-dependent. It is generally not a good idea to unlock someone else's mutex, even if it is allowed by the system.

Comment: @deft_code: I haven't read the mutex section of the FDIS yet, but I'd be astonished if it *isn't* a rule. Mutexes have an owner, it's part of their fundamental definition as a synchronization tool.

Comment: Here we are, 30.1.4.2/22: "Requires: the calling thread shall own the mutex". So UB if it doesn't.

Answer (score 10):

Since you have a case to use a semaphore, I think the fix is to portably [implement one using a mutex and a condition variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792449/c0x-has-no-semaphores-how-to-synchronize-threads).

This might not be especially efficient (since it'll use a mutex/condvar pair per semaphore), but you can switch in an alternate implementation on systems that have their own semaphores (such as Posix and Windows).

Apparently [semaphores are "too error-prone"](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2043.html#SemaphoreTypes). With all due respect to Boost, I think at least some of us can manage. Certainly you can tie yourself in knots [trying to do complicated things with multiple semaphores](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/64242/ImplementingCVs.pdf), and they are a pretty low-level tool. But when they're the right thing, no problem.

Comment: I agree that the "too error prone" thing is weird.  Mutexes can be error prone too.  So can a hammer.