# C++ multithreading stopping threads using concurrent variable

Tags: c++, multithreading, condition-variable

Trying to make a simple multithreading example using for loops. I'm trying to make them loop in block like this:

```
Thread 1 printing 0
Thread 2 printing 0
Thread 3 printing 0
Thread 4 printing 0
Thread 1 printing 1
Thread 2 printing 1
Thread 3 printing 1
Thread 4 printing 1
```

This means: they all print "1", then they all wait for everyone to have done that, then they all print "2", wait again for everyone, print "3", etc.

So I wrote this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

bool flags[4] = {true,true,true,true};

bool checkAll(){
    bool res = false;
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        res = res|flags[i];
    }
    return res;
}

void printer(int id){
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
        flags[id] = true;
    cout << "Thread: " << id << " printing " << i << endl;
    flags[id] = false;
    while(checkAll()) {}
}
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    thread t1(printer,0);
    thread t2(printer,1);
    thread t3(printer,2);
    thread t4(printer,3);

    t4.join();
    t3.join();
    t2.join();
    t1.join();

    return 0;
}
```

But it doesn't work as expected. As far as I know, it does not work due to concurrency problems (several threads reading/writing the same variable).

So, I tried to solve it using condition variables:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <string.h>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

using namespace std;

bool flags[4] = {true,true,true,true};
mutex m;
condition_variable g_queuecheck;
bool done = false;

bool checkAll(){
    bool res = false;
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        res = res|flags[i];
    }
    return res;
}

void printer(int id){
unique_lock<mutex> locker(m);
for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
    flags[id] = true;
    cout << "Thread: " << id << " printing " << i << endl;
    flags[id] = false;
    g_queuecheck.wait(locker);
}
}

void controller(){
while(!done){
    if(!checkAll()){
        g_queuecheck.notify_all();
    }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
thread t0(controller);
thread t1(printer,0);
thread t2(printer,1);
thread t3(printer,2);
thread t4(printer,3);

t4.join();
    t3.join();
    t2.join();
    t1.join();

    done = true;
    t0.join();

    return 0;
}
```

But doesn't work either. So, here come my questions: Is there a possible way of doing it simple like in the first code? If not, what am I doing wrong in the second one? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work" ? What output do you get in each of the above cases ?

Comment: Thread: 0 printing 0
Thread: 1 printing 0
Thread: 2 printing 0
Thread: 3 printing 0
Thread: 0 printing 1
Thread: 1 printing 1
Thread: 2 printing 1
Thread: 2 printing 2
Thread: 1 printing 2
Thread: 2 printing 3
Thread: 3 printing 1
Thread: 2 printing 4
Thread: 1 printing 3

And I'd like them to go in block, that means every one of them prints 1, wait till all have printed 1, then they all print 2, wait till all have printed 2, etc...

Comment: While there's certainly a way to do this I gotta ask why?  Most of the threads will be blocked most of the time and it'll likely be less efficient than a single threaded solution.

Comment: Well, i'm trying to develop something bigger with this, but right now i'm just trying to get this working using this stupid example. Obviously, is not useful and not efficient, but i'm trying to do it for the good of learning how to implement concurrency systems on c++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your examples do not work, because there are race conditions in updating and checking the flags array.

Seems like what you want though is a well known primitive called a [barrier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrier_(computer_science)). This can be implemented, for example, using [semaphores](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)). See section 3.6 of [The Little Book of Semaphores](http://greenteapress.com/semaphores/downey08semaphores.pdf) for details on how this works.

With a barrier your code can be written concisely as:

```
const int nThreads = 4;
const int nIter = 100;

mutex m;
barrier barrier(nThreads);


void printer(int id) {
  for (int i = 0; i < nIter; i++) {
    {  
      lock_guard<mutex> lock(m); // lock to prevent interleaved console output
      cout << "Thread: " << id << " printing " << i << endl;
    }
    barrier.wait();
  }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  vector<thread> ts;
  for (int i = 0; i < nThreads; i++) {
    ts.emplace_back(thread(printer, i));
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < nThreads; i++) {
    ts[i].join();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Below is a simple semaphore implementation (copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19659736/2924221)).

```
class semaphore {
private:
    mutex mtx;
    condition_variable cv;
    int count;

public:
    semaphore(int count_ = 0):count(count_){;}
    void notify()
    {
        unique_lock<mutex> lck(mtx);
        ++count;
        cv.notify_one();
    }
    void wait()
    {
        unique_lock<mutex> lck(mtx);

        while(count == 0){
            cv.wait(lck);
        }
        count--;
    }
};
```

Using that, you can implement a barrier as in the referenced book:

```
class barrier {
  public: 
    barrier(int n): n(n), count(0) {}

    void wait() {
      phase1();
      phase2();
    }
  private:
    mutex m;
    semaphore turnstile1, turnstile2;
    int n, count;

    void phase1() {
      m.lock();
      count++;
      if (count == n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
          turnstile1.notify();
      }
      m.unlock();
      turnstile1.wait();
    }

    void phase2() {
      m.lock();
      count--;
      if (count == 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            turnstile2.notify();  
      }
      m.unlock();
      turnstile2.wait();
    }
};
```

Comment: That solved the issue. Pretty complex though, but i'll give it a shot. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Well, this does what you want.  It worked without the `atomic` but I figured what the heck, throw it in anyway. :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <atomic>

const size_t num_threads = 10;
const size_t num_reps = 10;

std::mutex m;
std::atomic_int pos;

void printer(int id)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < num_reps; ++i)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(m);
        if(pos.load() == id)
        {
            std::cout << "Thread: " << id << " printing " << i << std::endl;
            pos.exchange((pos.load() + 1) % num_threads);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    m.lock();
    pos.store(0);
    std::vector<std::thread> v;
    for(int i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i)
    {
        v.emplace_back(std::thread(printer, i));
    }
    m.unlock();

    bool done;
    do
    {
        done = true;
        for(int i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i)
        {
            if(v[i].joinable())
            {
                done = false;
                v[i].join();
            }
        }
    }
    while(!done);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is all output I get from your code : Thread: 0 printing 0. Can't see what's wrong though

Comment: It's pretty crap code, I wouldn't be surprised if it deadlocked.  Works on Visual Studio 2013 though, perhaps by accident.  As I said in the comment, this isn't really something you'd normally see in real code.