# Using mutex and conditional variable instead of semaphore to print numbers from 1 to 10 in c++14?

Tags: multithreading, mutex, semaphore, c++14

I am trying to print numbers from 1 to n using two threads. One for incrementing, and the other for printing. Since there is no std library Semaphore class in new c++, I am using a mutex and a conditional variable to simulate a binary semaphore to do the job. The code below does not print any values but "main is here!". I checked my code several times and could not find a solution. Am I missing something here?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
using namespace std;

mutex m;
condition_variable cv;
int v=0;

void modify()
{
    while(v<10)
    {
        lock_guard<mutex> lock(m);
        v=v+1;

        cv.notify_all();
    }
}

void print()
{
    while(v<10)
    {
        unique_lock<mutex> lock(m);
        cv.wait(lock);
        cout<<v<<" ";
        lock.unlock();
        cv.notify_all();
    }
}

int main() {
    thread t1(modify);
    thread t2(print);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    cout<<endl<<"main is here!"<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implementation of semaphores is very simple and can be found here:
[C++0x has no semaphores? How to synchronize threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792449/c0x-has-no-semaphores-how-to-synchronize-threads)

But actually you does not need it

The problem of your code is that `modify` function does not wait for `print` function. See my changes to the code:

```cpp
void modify()
{
    // Fix #1: Any access to v should be done inside lock
    unique_lock<mutex> lock(m);

    while(v<10)
    {
        v=v+1;
        cv.notify_all();

        // Fix #2: wait for print function
        cv.wait(lock);
    }
}

void print()
{
    // See Fix #1
    unique_lock<mutex> lock(m);

    while(v<10)
    {
        cv.wait(lock);
        cout << v << " ";
        // Fix #3: no need to unlock here
        cv.notify_all();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. I implemented your changes but still nothing is printed. I use the online compiler at http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/ with the command g++ -std=c++14 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out

Comment: you need to insert std::flush as in "cout << flush()" to flush buffers