# Occassional thread sync fail after MFC ResumeThread and std::condition_variable wait

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, mfc, synchronization

**Background**
I am finishing up upgrading my MFC framework project from prototype to alpha production code. The task was to synchronize its threads. I used a mixture of mutexes, condition variables and binary semaphores. This has been mostly successful. The stackoverflow case that most resembles my question is [std::condition_variable wait() and notify_one() synchronization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33824499/stdcondition-variable-wait-and-notify-one-synchronization).

**Problem**
Occasionally, though, an atomicity problem occurs after new'ing a certain class derived from CWinThread (RxWs2SocketThread). RxWs2SocketThread switches to the new class'es thread and executes **InitInstance** and switches back again like it is supposed to. In single-threaded programs, when **ResumeThread** is called, the thread switch to InitInstance occurs without problem, but in my multithreaded program, I have to control the switching. Here is the code:

[image: Thread create and instantiate code]

The occasional fail occurs between line 95 and 102. Here is the app log showing a successful handoff:

[image: successful condition var wait after ResumeThread]

The number to the left is the thread number. Line numbers are in brackets like [100]. Note that [100] is the instrumentation for the actual **wait** call on line 102. And this app log shows an example of where it fails:

[image: unsuccessful cond var wait]

In this log, the **notify_one** occurs *before* the **wait**, which causes the program to hang. Note that line [100] in the app log, which represents the **wait** call in the code on line [102].

**Question**
This tells me I need to provide atomicity between the **ResumeThread** and **std::condition_variable.wait()** calls. How can I do that? I have to resume the class thread, otherwise the **InitInstance** won't be called, but I can't do a wait after I resume the thread.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the answer was right in front of me.
On code line 101, a lock is acquired on `rxWs2SocketInitInstanceMu` mutex. All I had to do was move the lock up to just before line 95 `ResumeThread`.

**Edit1:**
I switched out the `std::condition_varialble` synchronization primitive for `future/promise`. The former requires the use of separate locking, which does work when the locking statement is put before the `ResumeThread`, but this leads to error-prone maintenance. The `future/promise` primitive is designed to be one-off which is how it is used in my code.

> Note that the std::promise object is meant to be used only once (See cppreference)

.