# Can C++11 condition_variables be used to synchronize processes?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, semaphore, condition-variable

I'm trying to learn about C++11's `std::condition_variable`. I've read the articles at [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) and [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/condition_variable/condition_variable/) as well as [C++0x has no semaphores? How to synchronize threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792449/c0x-has-no-semaphores-how-to-synchronize-threads).

My question, which I think has not been answered by the three noted articles, is: can "semaphores" that are created with a combination of of `std::mutex` and `std::condition_variable` (see the answers to [C++0x has no semaphores? How to synchronize threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792449/c0x-has-no-semaphores-how-to-synchronize-threads)) be used to synchronize between processes the way posix named semaphores can be? It's not clear to me that this functionality can be achieved, because I don't see "sharable" information, such as a name, used in the creation of these objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, those are meant to synchronize threads within one process, not processes.

Interprocess communication is implemented by using shared files. An interprocess mutex or shared memory is just a file (created in your temp folder for instance) to exchange information (data, locks) between two processes. `boost::interprocess` offers an nice implementation of that (it does not require any link, code is compiled on the fly, you just need to include it).

To synchronize processes, you should have a look at [boost::interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/interprocess.html). It offers [synchronization mechanisms](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/interprocess/synchronization_mechanisms.html). It offers an [interprocess semaphore](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/interprocess/synchronization_mechanisms.html#interprocess.synchronization_mechanisms.semaphores).

Comment: I should have asked this along with my original question, but: it looks like the std::condition_variable also cannot be used like a counting semaphore, right? I see it makes use of std::uniqe_lock<std::mutex>, so it would seem usable as a binary semaphore only, right?

Comment: @StoneThrow: I would say yes, but you should ask a separate question to have a clear answer to that.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing to IPC (inter process communication) in standard C++ is file io.

There is no in-memory IPC in standard C++.