# How do I deal with the system clock changing while waiting on a std::condition_variable?

Tags: c++, c++11, time, condition-variable, system-clock

I'm trying to implement some cross-platform code in C++11.  Part of this code implements a semaphore object using a [`std::condition_variable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable).  When I need to do a timed wait on the semaphore, I use [`wait_until`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait_until) or [`wait_for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait_for).

The problem I'm experiencing is that it seems like the standard implementation of `condition_variable` on POSIX-based systems relies [on the system clock, rather than the monotonic clock](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-closed.html#887) (see also: [this issue against the POSIX spec](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=1164))

That means that if the system clock gets changed to some time in the past, my `condition_variable` will block for far longer than I expect it to. For instance, if I want my `condition_variable` to time out after 1 second, if someone adjusts the clock back 10 minutes during the wait, the `condition_variable` blocks for 10 minutes + 1 second. I've confirmed that this is the behavior on an Ubuntu 14.04 LTS system.

I need to rely on this timeout to be at least somewhat accurate (i.e., it can be inaccurate within some margin of error, but still needs to execute if the system clock changes). It seems like what I'm going to need to do is write my own version of `condition_variable` that uses the POSIX functions and implements the same interface using the monotonic clock.

That sounds like A Lot Of Work - and kind of a mess. Is there some other way of working around this issue?

Comment: check Boost specs?

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Boost apparently had this issue and fixed it around 1.60/1.61.  However, I can't use Boost in this situation.  I may be able to copy their implementation, but I'd really rather not have to provide and maintain my own implementation of condition_variable if I can avoid it.  That's kind of the *library's* job, IMHO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After considering the possible solutions to this problem, the one that seems to make the most sense is to ban the use of `std::condition_variable` (or at least make the caveat clear that it is always going to use the system clock). Then I have to basically re-implement the standard library's `condition_variable` myself, in a way that respects the clock choice.

Since I have to support multiple platforms (Bionic, POSIX, Windows, and eventually MacOS), that means I'm going to maintain several versions of this code.

While this is nasty, it seems like the alternatives are even nastier.

Answer (score 6):

I encountered the same problem. A colleague of mine gave me a tip to use certain C functions from `<pthread.h>` instead and it worked out wonderfully for me.

As an example, I had:

```
std::mutex m_dataAccessMutex;
std::condition_variable m_dataAvailableCondition;
```

with its standard usage:

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> _(m_dataAccessMutex);
// ...
m_dataAvailableCondition.notify_all();
// ...
m_dataAvailableCondition.wait_for(...);
```

The above can be replaced by using `pthread_mutex_t` and `pthread_cond_t`. The advantage is that you can specify the clock to be monotonic. Brief usage example:

```
#include <pthread.h>

// Declare the necessary variables
pthread_mutex_t m_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_condattr_t m_attr;
pthread_cond_t m_cond;

// Set clock to monotonic
pthread_condattr_init(&m_attr);
pthread_condattr_setclock(&m_attr, CLOCK_MONOTONIC);
pthread_cond_init(&m_cond, &m_attr); 

// Wait on data
struct timespec ts;
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ts);
ts.tv_sec += timout_in_seconds; 
pthread_mutex_lock(&m_mutex);
int rc = pthread_cond_timedwait(&m_cond, &m_mutex, &ts);
if (rc != ETIMEDOUT)
    ; // do things with data
else 
    ; // error: timeout
// ...
pthread_mutex_unlock(&m_mutex); // have to do it manually to unlock
// ...

// Notify the data is ready
pthread_cond_broadcast(&m_cond);
```

Answer (score 3):

Register your active condition variables centrally.

Do some effort to detect the clock error, even if it is a thread spin-locking on the current clock (ick) or some other means.

When you detect a clock error, poke the condition variable.

Now wrap your condition variables in a thin wrapper that also supports detecting the clock slippage.  It invokes `wait_until` but replaces the predicate with one that detects clock slippage, and when that happens breaks out of the wait.

When your implementation is broken, you gotta do what you gotta do.

Comment: This is an absolutely awful solution to this problem. About the only thing worse is the other possible solutions to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the best solution, or a great solution, but you did say "work around" and not "a lot of work", so:

- Use your distribution's facilities to monitor changes to the system clock (I'm not quite sure what these facilities are; at worst, you can run a cron job every 5 minutes to check the clock is around its expected value).
- Upon detection of a system clock change, communicate something to the process in which you have your waiting/sleeping threads. You might use a signal; or a pipe; or a unix-domain socket; or even some shared memory.
- On the process' side, make sure you receive this (i.e. write a signal handler, or have a thread doing blocking I/O on the pipe; or polling the shared memory using non-`std::condition_variable` sleep - respectively)
- Upon receiving notification regarding a change to the system clock, shake things up in your process, awaken sleeping threads, and re-assess what needs to be done based on the altered time. Maybe it's exactly the same as before, in which case you simply have your threads using the condition variable again.

Not very elegant, and there's a bunch of overhead involved - but this does make sense, and isn't some crazy hack.