# How to write a blockng waitUntil() method to a pool that uses std::atomics

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, lock-free

I have a validation class that uses ah threadpool to process all of its jobs.

Now, when the user asks, I start a thread that feeds my validation class with jobs by reading from disk. And I am certain that at one point reading will be faster than processing. So I want to write a method that allows this thread to wait if there are more than, say, 1000 jobs being processed.

I already introduced an atomic that increases when a job is added and decreases when one is finished.

My attempt to add a method have been less than pretty. And I know it must be possible to use something better.

```
void Validator::waitUntilAvailable() {
    while (m_blocksInFlight > 1000) { // thats my atomic
        usleep(50000); // seems to be unavailable on Windows.
    }
}
```

Would anyone here be able to assist in having a non-polling method to solve my issue?

Thank you.

Comment: sounds like a perfect use for a semaphore

Comment: ... a simple implementation here: https://gist.github.com/sguzman/9594227

Comment: @RichardHodges Looks like a copy from http://stackoverflow.com/a/4793662/412080

Comment: `std::this_thread::sleep_for(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a condition that your would like to wait for, but no waiting mechanism.

That mechanism is `std::condition_variable` and `std::mutex`. E.g.:

```
class Validator
{
    std::mutex m_mutex;
    std::condition_variable m_condition;
    std::atomic<int> m_blocksInFlight{0};

    bool test() const {
        return m_blocksInFlight.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) > 1000;
    }

    void addJob() {
        ++m_blocksInFlight;

        // Only lock the mutex when the test succeeds.
        if(this->test()) {
            std::unique_lock<decltype(m_mutex)> lock(m_mutex);
            m_condition.notify_one();
        }
    }

    void waitUntilAvailable() {
        std::unique_lock<decltype(m_mutex)> lock(m_mutex);
        while(!this->test())
            m_condition.wait(lock);
    }
};
```

Comment: I've read about the condition, but have not understood fully how it would apply.

How would the code that decreases the m_blocksInFlight atomic look? I'm assuming it would need to do something with the mutex too?