# An efficient event loop implementation?

Tags: events, event-loop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How would you implement a basic event-loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658403/how-would-you-implement-a-basic-event-loop)

Not really a language-specific question. What could be an efficient implementation of event loop? So far I've only encountered something like this:

```
while (true) {
    handleEvents();
    sleep(100);
}
```

which I don't think is the best way - if sleep duration is too short, it will eat lots of cpu, and if it's too long, the app will be pretty unresponsive.

So, is there a better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most common pattern is:

```
while (WaitForNextEvent()) {
    HandleEvent();
}
```

With `WaitForNextEvent()` returning `false` to indicate there are no more events to process, and, most importantly, being able to perform a *blocking wait* for the next event.

For instance, the event source might be a file, a socket, the thread's message queue or another [waitable object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687028.aspx) of some kind. In that case, you can guarantee that `HandleEvent()` only runs if an event is ready, and is triggered very shortly after an event becomes ready.

Comment: Thanks, I googled some things about epoll, select, libevent and things like that, seems like they do what I want :)