# c++ not let main return

Tags: c++, destructor

I have the following code:

```
int main()
{
    Client *c = new Client();
    ExitOnlyWhenClientException();
    return 0;
}
```

So I don't want main to return only when client throws exception. I know I can use condition variable, which signal in client's destructor and wait in main block.

But Is there another method?

I've found this link [How would you implement a basic event-loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658403/how-would-you-implement-a-basic-event-loop)

My question here is a little different compared to above link, since it shoud know client crashed.

**EDIT 1**

I made a mistake to say crash, which I really mean exception.

Comment: `Client` seems to be a class. A class doesn't crash. A program crashes. Therefore if the code in the `Client` class causes a crash, the whole program goes down. Unless you are talking about exceptions, which are a different matter.

Comment: Which platform? The concept of an event loop is likely in the 1st chapter of any basic tutorial. @SirDarius: It's pretty obvious he means "when Client causes a crash".

Comment: Why no just have a run method on the client, call it and then you'll have to wait til it finished, either via a crash or cleanly

Comment: @SirDarius: Yes, I mean client throwes exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's replace `Client` with another class type:

```
int main()
{
    std::string *s = new std::string();
    ExitOnlyWhenStringException();
    return 0;
}
```

Now, `std::string::at()` could throw an exception if you tried to access an out-of-bound element. And in fact, since `*s` is empty, any index will be out of bounds.  However, you are not calling `s->at(8)` or any other method. So, the only possible exception is a `std::bad_alloc` from `new`. You won't need to handle that (Any reasonable implementation will allow you to crate at least one object dynamically).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am sorry for I'm not very clear of my question.